# t-structures over a discrete valuation ring

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

I am struggling the exercise 6 of Problem Set 3 of [Bhargav Bhatt's problem sets](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bhattb/teaching/mat731f15/). Given a d.v.r. $R$, and $\mathcal D$ is the full subcategory of the derived category of $R$, spanned by bounded complexes with finitely generated homology; and $(\mathcal D^{\le0},\mathcal D^{>0})$ is a non-degenerate t-structure on $\mathcal D$.

The ultimate goal is to show that any non-degenerate t-structure is a shift of the standard t-structure, or a shift of the dual of the t-structure (we note that $\operatorname{RHom}(-,R)$ is an auto-duality).

Let's assume that $R\in\mathcal D^{\ge0}\setminus\mathcal D^{\ge1}$. One is supposed to show that $R\in\mathcal D^{=0}$, (the abuse) of the notation of $\mathcal D^{\ge0}\cap\mathcal D^{\le0}$, i.e., the heart, with the hint to consider the distinguished triangle $H_t^0(R)\to R\to\tau_t^{\ge1}R$, where $H_t^0$ (resp. $\tau_t$) is the cohomology functor (resp. truncation functor) defined by the t-structure.

Here's what I tried: Note that the standard $H^0$ is a cohomology functor. Apply it to the distinguished triangle, we get a long exact sequence, and leads to isomorphisms $H^i(\tau_t^{\ge1}R)\cong H^{i+1}(H_t^0(R))$, where $i\neq-1,0$. The left hand side belongs to $\mathcal D^{\ge1-i}$ (here we used the fact that bounded complexes over a d.v.r. is quasi-isomorphic to the direct sum of cohomologies with shifts), while the right hand side belongs to $\mathcal D^{=-1-i}$ (a translation of the heart), hence $0$ by degeneracy. We are left to analyze $$0\to H^{-1}(\tau_t^{\ge1}R)\to H^0(H_t^0(R))\xrightarrow\alpha R\to H^0(\tau_t^{\ge1}R)\to H^1(H_t^0(R))\to0$$
Since $R$ is a PID, $\operatorname{im}\alpha$ is principal, therefore isomorphic to $R$ or $0$. The first case leads to the result. I have trouble with the second case, which leads to a short exact sequence:
$$0\to R\to H^0(\tau_t^{\ge1}R)\to H^1(H_t^0(R))\to0$$
It seems to me that this will imply that $R\in\mathcal D^{\ge1}$. I failed to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, $H^0(\tau_t^{\geq1}R)$ has a submodule isomorphic to $R$. But if a finitely generated module for a d.v.r. $R$ has a free submodule then (by the classification of finitely generated modules for a PID) it has a free direct summand. So $R$ is a summand of $\tau_t^{\geq1}$, and so $R\in\mathcal{D}^{\geq1}$, contradicting the original assumption.

Comment: Ah, interesting enough, although it does not necessarily split. Does the same trick work for (b), namely one of the maps $\tau_t^{\le i}k\to k$ or $k\to\tau_t^{\ge i+1}k$ is an isomorphism? Seemingly it reduces to a similar 6-term exact sequence.

Comment: @FrankScience I think the easiest way to approach that question is to note that since the maximal ideal of $R$ annihilates $k$, it must annihilate any functor of $k$. So by the classification of finitely generated $R$-modules, and the fact that every object of the derived category is a direct sum of shifts of modules, objects such as $\tau_t^{\leq i}k$ must be direct sums of shifts of $k$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your remark. I cannot see how an arbitrary additive functor "preserves" annihilators. On the other hand, there is a distinguished triangle $R\to k\to\Sigma\mathfrak m\to\Sigma R$, where $\mathfrak m$ doesn't annihilate $R$, $\Sigma\mathfrak m$, so the machinery doesn't work for all decompositions.

Comment: @FrankScience If $F$ is an $R$-linear functor, and multiplication by $r\in R$ acts as zero on $X$, then multiplication by $r$ acts as zero on $FX$. In your example triangle, there is no $R$-linear functor that sends $k$ to $R$. The point is that the functoriality of the "truncation" triangle gives more information than just the existence of the triangle for one particular object.